# Pros & Cons: Hibernate vs. EJB 3

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

What are the advantages and disadvantages of Hibernate & EJB3 relative to each other?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683660/ejb-vs-hibernate) post, but it didn't really address my question. If I don't have any particular tie to either technology, what would cause me to pick one over the other? Or are there situations where I would want to use both?

Thanks,
Zack

*edit: in response to comments: I don't know much about EJB3. I'm just trying to learn if it's something that would be viable for my company. If EJB3 isn't comparable to Hibernate, please explain why.*

Comment: Wow! really sticky question. I guess the team with faster release/defect-fix cycles wins this round. As long as hibernate adheres to JPA spec this question would lurk, but if they decide to branch-off and incorporate some really nice features then...

Comment: Hibernate and EJB3 do not compare. EJB3 and spring can be compared instead.

Comment: @Bozho I think what he meant to ask was Hibernate vs. JPA (which is often mixed up with EJB3)

Comment: You should clarify the question. If your question is about Hibernate and JPA, then rewrite it because EJB3 is more than JPA and you can't compare EJB3 as a whole with Hibernate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JPA provides a subset of Hibernate functionality, but EJB3 provides other services that Hibernate does not address (e.g. Web services, EJBs, Timer service)

JPA offers the following benefits compared to Hibernate:

- Standardized API
- Vendor independence (can switch between Hibernate, TopLink, OpenEJB, etc.)

Hibernate offers the following benefits:

- Widely used
- De facto standard
- Direct support from Spring, Grails, etc.
- Possibly better tools support
- More features than JPA

What you can do is write your application in EJB using JPA and then when necessary use Hibernate-specific features. Or just use plain Hibernate for persistence if you don't care about standardization and vendor lock-in. Realistically, it's unlikely you will switch between Hibernate and another provider, but it does happen.

Comment: Nitpick: Spring also supports JPA